# SSRS running very slow and error client rendering

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report rendered through sharepoint site. 
and i come across an error message:

### Unsupported RPL stream version detected: 109.108.1112887328. Expected version: 10.6.

An error occurred during client rendering.

can anyone give me some idea how to solve.

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try with re-staring your SQL Server Agent? and also take a look into https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/355502/unsupported-rpl-stream-version-detected-10-0-0-expected-version-10-3

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint, MS lists this as a not reproducible bug, https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/355502/unsupported-rpl-stream-version-detected-10-0-0-expected-version-10-3

If you aren't using SharePoint, like me, a restart of the SSRS service will fix this.